# What are common reasons afci circuits won't work?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I rewired my house and installed 8 GFCI, afci and dual function circuit breakers on my 120 volt circuits. They all trip with any type of load, however standard circuit breakers work fine.

Comment: Are you sure you wired them correctly? Is your service properly grounded? A photo of the panel may show us something you are unaware of.

Comment: Did you move the neutral wire for each circuit off the neutral bar and onto the breaker?

Comment: What make and model is your panel, and what make and model of breakers are we dealing with here?

Comment: This may be a dumb comment, but when you say you re-wired the house, what did that entail?  Did you do a service panel swap?  If not, are you sure you have the neutrals connected to the SAME GFCI Breakers as it's corresponding hot?  It's critical that the neutral and the hot for a circuit is connected to the same GFCI breaker. While I agree with DoxyLover that you may have some interconnected neutrals someplace, the fact that none of them work leads me to believe a wiring issue in the panel. Again, be sure the hots and neutrals go to the same breaker for each circuit.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You might want to take our tour which will best explain how to participate here. On these type of questions more detail will result in a better answer. Pictures and detailed descriptions of work done prior to the problem in question are helpful.

Comment: Thanks Ed, so far I have added to ground rods, cleaned and reinstalled the cold water ground.

Comment: Yes, it turned out I had wired them incorrectly - maybe I'll have to start reading directions!

Answer (score 2):

This almost always results from mixed of interconnected neutrals. If you have a connection between neutrals of different circuits, or the neutrals are switched, then the current through the GFCI circuitry is unbalanced, causing the trip.

The other thing to check is that you moved the neutral wires from the neutral bus to the neutral terminals of the breakers.

To debug this, turn off all of the breakers and disconnect all of the neutrals (mark them to keep track of where they go). Check for continuity between neutrals. If you find any, you’ll need to track down where they are connected.

If none are connected, turn on a load (e.g. light bulb) on each circuit. Go to each hot and find the neutral that shows some continuity. Make sure these are paired on a breaker.